# Can DESC statement used inside SELECT Statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Can any one tell me how to use the desc statement inside select statement?

I need to display the structure of the table using select statement.

Comment: Please describe your expected output by using "desc inside select statement"

Comment: `DESC`, in SQL DQL, is a modifier of `ORDER BY`. It is used *with* `ORDER BY`. So - "Can ORDER BY statement used inside SELECT Statement?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be referring to/thinking of the `DESCRIBE` statement, as in `DESCRIBE MYTABLE;`

If so - the answer is No.

```
SELECT * FROM (DESC MYTABLE); -- Is Invalid

DESC MYTABLE; -- Is Valid
```

What you need is `SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE'`

Answer (score 2):

You can get a simple column listing by saying

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 0=1
```

But for more than that, you should follow Manjunath's advice and use `user_tables`.

Answer (score 0):

Select statement is enough to describe the table structure , If you are on oracle , use user_tables to get this done .